# How to hide an element by condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going to set a parameter for an iframe that sets to 1 or 0.  then if the parameter is 1 a div by `class="badge"` will visible else hide.

How can I define this condition in JavaScript? Thank you for your help :)

This is my HTML and CSS code.

```css
.badge {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #7bbded;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 1px 6px 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<iframe scrolling="no" style="" src="" frameborder="0">

<div id="main" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<div class="ad-container" id="container">
<a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="cmp_link_clicked()">
<img class="text-icon" alt="آموزش های فرادرس" title="آموزش های فرادرس" src="https://beta.kaprila.com/a/images/video-icon.gif">
<h3 id="title">فیلم‌&nbsp;آموزشی <span class="important">تافل <span class="ltr">(TOEFL)</span></span> تشریح آزمون — <strong>کلیک کنید</strong></h3>

<div class="badge" id="badge" style="display: block;">
تبلیغات
</div>
</a>
</div>

</div>




</iframe>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get a reference to the div:

```
var div = document.querySelector('.badge');
```

Then, add a new class, like `show`:

```
if(parameter === 1){
 div.classList.add('show');
}
```

`parameter` should be the name of your parameter stored in a var.

Besides, you could set `display: block` in your css file, not as inline style.

Like this:

```
.badge {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #7bbded;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 1px 6px 0 3px;
    display:none; // ---> Hidden by default
}

.badge.show {
    display:block; // --> Visible only when you have .badge and .show classes in the same element
}
```

To remove the class, you can use `classList.remove('show');`

```
if(parameter === 0){
    div.classList.remove('show');
}
```

Check docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: @mahsayadegari, if it worked, can you select answer as right, please?